# Is $ \cos² y = 0 $ a solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I'm studying math for school. We're solving separable differential equations. One of the exercises is:

$$ \frac{\Bbb d y}{\Bbb d x} = \frac{  (\cos y)^2 \tan y }{1+x²}$$

If you separate the variables you get:

$$ \frac{\Bbb d y}{ (\cos y )^2  \tan y } =  \frac{\Bbb d x}{ 1+x²} $$

If:  $ (\cos y)^2 \tan y \ne 0$, then $ (\cos y)^2 \ne 0$ and $\tan y \ne 0$. That is where my question comes in.

My course says the following: 
$\cos y = 0 \Rightarrow y = \frac \pi 2 + k \pi $, which is not a solution.

$ \tan y = 0 \Rightarrow y = 0 + k \pi \Rightarrow y = k\pi $  is a solution.

I don't get that. Why is $ \cos y = 0 $ not a solution and  $\tan y = 0$ is? I know that $y = 0$ when $\tan y = 0$, but what's up with the $k\pi$? What does that mean?

Comment: Why do you need $\cos y=0$ or $\tan y=0$? Aren't you solving a differential equation?

Comment: I think it is because of the $\frac{1}{\cos^2 y \tan y}$ and what happens if either one of those is $0$.

Comment: Indeed, Chinny is right.

Comment: If for some x one of them is zero then simply you say that this x is not in the domain of the solution y if any

Comment: Start by solving the differential équation to find y and then ask yourself what is the biggest interval in which it is defined and here equal or not to zero is involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\cos y=0$ means $y=\pi/2+k\pi$, but these are not solutions because $\tan y$ on the right hand side is not defined for $y=\pi/2+k\pi$: as you know, $\tan y=\sin y/\cos y$, so $\tan y$ is not defined when $\cos y=0$.

Comment: Thank you, I get that part now!!

Just one more question.. What does the k*pi stand for? Isn't y just equal to 0, when tan y = 0? Why the k*pi?

Comment: @user257840 Note that $\tan$ is a periodic function, $\tan (y + k\pi) = \tan y$ when $k \in \mathbb Z$. So if $y = 0$ is a solution to $\tan y = 0$ then $k\pi, k \in \mathbb Z$ also is

Comment: You should revise some trig equation theory: $k\pi$ stands for *add an arbitrary number of straight angles*. That is: not only $y=\pi/2$ is a solution to $\cos y=0$, but also $\pi/2 +\pi$, $\pi/2+2\pi$ and so on.

Comment: I get it! Thank you so much, guys! I'll need to revise some trig indeed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\cos^2y\tan y}{1+x^2}$$ $$\frac{dy}{\cos^2 y\tan y}=\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$ Integrating both the sides we get $$\int \frac{dy}{\cos^2 y\tan y}=\int \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$ $$\int \frac{\sec^2y dy}{\tan y}=\int \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$let $\tan y=t\implies \sec^2ydy=dt$, we get $$\ln (\tan y)=\tan^{-1}(x)+C$$

**Edit**: Notice, in right side of above equation,

if $cos^2y=0\implies y=n\pi\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ for which $\tan y$ is undefined thus it can't be a solution.

if you take $\tan y=0$ then $\ln (\tan y)$ is undefined so it can't be a solution.

Comment: Yes, that part I get. Eventually the explicit solution is

y = bgtg (c * e^bgtgx) + k*pi

And that k*pi comes from my original question. And I don't get why.

Bgtg is btw our notation for tan^-1.

Comment: That's an answer to another question, OP asks about possible solutions when $\cos^2 y = 0$ and $\tan y = 0$, not about the general case